# DCEF3 How disable focus after load page?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium

I use DCEF3 (Delphi 7 TChromium) and have troubles with focus. On my Form I've a TDBGrid element and TChromium. When I move on the records on DBGrid, then Chromium load information page. And this work well, except focus problem: after load end TChromium fetch focus for self. How I can disable TChromium take focus after load page?

Comment: This does not happen on my computer. You can use SelectFirst/SelectNext/SetFocus to set focus if needed.

Comment: One more thing ... you can use event Chromium.OnSetFocus and set its Result to "True".

Comment: Thanks, almost! If Chromium.OnSetFocus set Result to "True" its realy help for focus stay in the dbgrid, but, scrolling in Chromium don't working after that! Loaded page stay clickable, so its ok, but not scrolling, but not form fill, etc

Comment: Yep! Correct code will be with testing source: if source = FOCUS_SOURCE_NAVIGATION then Result:=True else Chromium.SetFocus;

Answer (score 3):

add event Chromium.OnSetFocus

if source = FOCUS_SOURCE_NAVIGATION then Result:=True else Chromium.SetFocus;

Comment: You're supposed to return false to allow the focus to be set, not explicitly calling `SetFocus`. So simple `Result := source = FOCUS_SOURCE_NAVIGATION;` should suffice.

Comment: Then it might be a CEF issue, because that is how the [`OnSetFocus`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefFocusHandler.html#OnSetFocus) event should be handled.

Comment: I have tested with CEF4 and this problem still exists. Thanks for solutions.